# TFS 2018 On-premise How to build and deploy multiple tenant sites

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, filtering, continuous-deployment

Using On-premise TFS 2018.  Looking for advice to build and deploy multiple tenants to IIS with the below structure. We are using GIT for the source control.

Each tenant is a customized 'clone' of a .Net Core 2.0 website.  It shares some basic functionality through assemblies, but offers per-tenant customizations.
Each tenant has its own Visual Studio 2017 sln and csproj file.  For now the solution references the shared assembly directly (as we are not as yet using nuget for our shared assemblies).

The structure is:

```
Tenants (GIT repository)
  L Share Assemblies
    L assmbly1.csproj
    L assmbly2.csproj
  L Projects
    L PRJ1
      L PRJ1.sln (prj1.csproj, and customized files)
    L PRJ2
      L PRJ2.sln (prj2.csproj, and customized files)
    L PRJN
      L PRJN.sln (prjn.csproj, and customized files)
```

What I am interested in is advice on how to deploy (via continuous deployment) to tenants that 1) have changes at the project level, and 2) tenants that use shared assemblies that have changed.

We have the potential for our tenants to grow very large, so we don't want to deploy all tenants on each build.

Is there a way to filter so we only deploy tenants that have changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a separate environment for each tenant and add an approval to deploy to the environment.

Other option could be have one environment and many phases, one for each tenant. I prefer the first one.

Another one could be to have a file and create a powershell script to create a loop and deploy for each tenant. This one is more complex to implement.

Comment: Can you be more specific on option 3?  Specifically how would a file help (does it contained a list of the changed tenants)? If so, how to detect changes to create that file and how to loop through it in powershell.